# Daemon can't be started from fabric script or on boot - only interactively

Tags: linux, python, daemon, tcpdump, fabric

I have a daemon script in /etc/init.d that performs some background packet logging using the **tcpdump** command. The script starts up fine using an interactive shell using **sudo /etc/init.d/packetlog start**

When I execute the same command through my fabric script (below) the command returns successfully but the process is not running.

```
def startpacketlog():
    sudo(r'/etc/init.d/packetlog start')
```

Further to this, the service does not start automatically on boot as I had expected.

Some tips for troubleshooting this would be appreciated

The script is [here](http://pastebin.com/UZXEXZna) and is modified from this [original](http://www.3open.org/d/untangle/tcpdump.init)

**Update**
This seems to be a general problem with starting any service on this host using fabric. When starting the apache2 service I get the same problem. I can stop the service using fabric successfully though.

**Update 2** 
After re-reading [the documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/api/core/operations.html) and some experimentation the following change fixed the problem. (This disables the remote pseudo-terminal, whatever that is)

```
def startpacketlog():
    sudo(r'/etc/init.d/packetlog start',pty=False)
```

Comment: might help if you post the fabric line you are using

Comment: good point - I've added it now

Answer (score 3):

When you invoke an init script directly, your current environment can "leak" into the init script.

Test your init script using the appropriate system tools:

```
# Redhat/CentOS, and Ubuntu with upstart
sudo service packetlog start

# traditional method on Debian/Ubuntu 
sudo invoke-rc.d packetlog start
```

These will make sure the script is starting in a clean environment, identical to the one it would be in when started by init.